# Android: make users migrate from a paid version of an app back to free, preserving the benefits

Tags: android, android-inapp-purchase

I have a free and a paid version of the same app on Google Play. Two different applications.

The paid version is the same as the free one except it has some bonus features.

I want to stop maintaining 2 applications and only support the free version.

My question is how can I give any kind of token (using inapp purchases mechanism or anyhow) to my paid app users so that using that token they can enter it somehow into the free version and I will then unlock the features in there.

Comment: Just a thought: If you offer in-app purchases in your free app then you *might* be able to offer promo codes from within your paid app and have users enter their code (one per user) in the free app. I believe it depends on the number of users though. If you have more than 500, you can't do it this way.

Worth taking a look though...
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6321495